# Why does loss and accuracy for a multi label classification ann does not change overtime?

Tags: neural-networks, accuracy, loss

I have run into a strange behavior of my **multi label** classification ANN

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(6, input_shape=(input_size,), activation='elu'))
#model.add(BatchNormalization(axis=-1))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
#model.add(BatchNormalization(axis=-1))
model.add(Dense(6, activation='elu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
#model.add(BatchNormalization(axis=-1))
model.add(Dense(6, activation='elu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))

# model.add(keras.layers.BatchNormalization(axis=-1))
model.add(Dense(6, activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
              optimizer='nadam',
              metrics=['accuracy'])
history = model.fit(X_train, Y_train,batch_size=64 ,epochs=300,
                    validation_data = (X_test, Y_test), verbose=2)
```

The result is quite strange, I have a feeling that my model could not improve any more. Why does the loss and the accuracy does not change overtime ?

P/S For clarification, I have 6 output and the value of each output is 0 or 1 that is
output 1: can be 0 or 1

output 2: can be 0 or 1

output 3: can be 0 or 1

output 4: can be 0 or 1

output 5: can be 0 or 1

output 6: can be 0 or 1

[image]

Comment: Hi ! How many samples do you have in X_train ? Can you try to visualize the outputs on your test set (for instance, are your predictions constants ?) ? Maybe one problem is that you put a lot of Dropout, and your network is already narrow so instead of preventing overfitting this could hinder the learning...

Comment: about 4000 training samples, and validate 1000 samples.The output for each test set data point is a binary output vector that is 

[out1 out2 out3 out4 out5 out6]


Particularly

 output 1: can be 0 or 1

output 2: can be 0 or 1

output 3: can be 0 or 1

output 4: can be 0 or 1

output 5: can be 0 or 1

output 6: can be 0 or 1

Comment: Okay. Why did you use Dropout and Batch norm ? It may be useful to visualize the actual predictions of your trained net. You know, using for instance `plt.scatter(Y_test, model.predict(X_test))`

Comment: (As you have multi label classification, you may plot `plt.scatter(Y_test, model.predict(X_test))` for each particular label)